# Problems linking stylesheet to html doc

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to teach myself html/css. I can't get Aptana to recognize my css stylesheet.

Here's what I have for my html file (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Josh's Worthwhile Practice</title>
        <meta name="author" content="Joshua Soileau" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <!-- Date: 2012-07-11 -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><h4>Solutions</h4><p>what we do</p></li>
                <li><h4>Work</h4><p>what we've done</p></li>
                <li><h4>Team</h4><p>who we are</p></li>
                <li id="nav_logo">LOGO</li>
                <li><h4>Blog</h4><p>stuff we say</p></li>
                <li><h4>Contact</h4><p>talk to us</p></li>
                <li><h4>Client</h4><p>login</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my .css file (style.css, in the same directory as index.html)

```css
* {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#nav {
    color: #121415;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

I have the link tag in my html code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

But when I open index.html in a browser or the Aptana preview pane, it just shows the plain html with none of my css pulled in.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. I had left an empty css tag in the file and Aptana didn't like it. This is my fault, I left it out of this post because I didn't think it was relevant.

I had:

```
#nav li {}
```

Sorry for not given you guys all the info, you were all very helpful and I helped me learn some new things. Thanks!

Comment: Remember, if you have solved/answered your own question, accept it as the answer: [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `type="text/css"` attribute. Most modern browsers will complain if a `type` is specified and doesn't exactly match the `Content-Type` header the file returns, and when loading files locally there is no `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried it, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Your style.css file must be in the same location as index.html for it to work.

What do you see in the address bar of the browser when previewing?

What happens if you replace index.html with style.css? Are you able to see the CSS file?

Does it work without Aptana's preview, if you open the index.html file directly?

Also open up firebug or developer tools and hit the network tab to check if the browser is making a request for the CSS file and what if any errors are being reported. Also check the response headers.

You may also want to verify what Aptana is doing to your source after it generates the preview. Does doing a view source in the preview browser show the exact same link / path to the stylesheet?

Do you have a similar issue as this user with absolute path's in Aptana's preview: [Aptana Studio 3 preview problems with absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669664/aptana-studio-3-preview-problems-with-absolute-path)

Comment: My index.html and style.css are in the same directory, replacing index.html in the addr bar with style.css pulls up the stylesheet. Firebug doesn't show any errors and my code validates fine in aptana, although I don't know what the network tab is or how to check if the browser is making a request for the css file or not, as I am just beginning : \

Comment: Does it work if you open up the index.html file directly in a browser and not with apatan's preview?

Comment: In firebug, Its the 'Net' tab.

Comment: Yep, I can open it directly from the folder in finder to chrome or firefox just fine. It loads up the html without any problems.

Comment: @Josh: You mean, it loads up the file with the styling applied?

Comment: Also what version of Aptana are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure aptana has autocomplete on files and other html/css tags so try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="
```

I believe that when you have typed this if should start to give you all the files within your folder hysterical set up. If it doesn't try a `/` or the likes?

Answer (score 0):

try putting it in a folder for example CSS

```
<link href="CSS/aki.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
```